# problem faced during sending attach file using mail -a

Tags: linux

i am using a Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS release 4 (Nahant Update 8) and i am facing problems while i try to send an attached file via email using "mail -a" option.
the below is displayed:

```
mail -a
mail: invalid option -- a
Usage: mail [-iInv] [-s subject] [-c cc-addr] [-b bcc-addr] to-addr ...
            [- sendmail-options ...]
       mail [-iInNv] -f [name]
       mail [-iInNv] [-u user]
```

The rpm packages installed related to "mail" are:

```
rpm -qa | grep mail
sendmail-8.13.1-3.3.el4
mailx-8.1.1-37.EL4
mailcap-2.1.17-1
procmail-3.22-14.1.el4
```

Please, can you tell me what .rpm package i should install on my system in order to be able to use "mail -a".

thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Where did you find that -a option?
You should have a look at the pair `uuencode`/`uudecode` to attach binary files to your mails.

Answer (score 0):

Try *mailx*

```
NAME
   mailx - send and receive Internet mail

SYNOPSIS
   mailx [-BDdEFintv~] [-s subject] [-a attachment ] [-c cc-addr] [-b bcc-addr] [-r from-addr] [-h hops] [-A account] [-S variable[=value]] to-addr . . .
   mailx [-BDdeEHiInNRv~] [-T name] [-A account] [-S variable[=value]] -f [name]
   mailx [-BDdeEinNRv~] [-A account] [-S variable[=value]] [-u user]
```